# Why does dollar not match literal dollar when extended regex (ERE) option is used with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I want to replace `$foo` with `bar`. This works fine.

```
$ echo '$foo' | sed 's/$foo/bar/'
bar
```

But this command does not work fine when I use the `-r` option.

```
$ echo '$foo' | sed -r 's/$foo/bar/'
$foo
```

Why doesn't this work.

Here is an example of what works with `-r` option.

```
$ echo '$foo' | sed -r 's/\$foo/bar/'
bar
```

The real question is: Why does `$` need to be escaped only while using the `-r` option. What would `$` mean otherwise with the `-r` option?

I am using a Debian Linux system.

Comment: You don't want to expand the `$foo` variable on using `-r`?

Comment: `echo '$foo' | sed -r 's/\$foo/bar/'`?

Comment: $foo will be expanded by shell when you use double quotation mark `" "`.

Comment: @gzh The `$` in `$foo` is already escaped with `\$`, so it should not be escaped. Try `echo "\$foo"`.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus What you are suggesting is equivalent to `echo '$foo' | sed -r "s/\\\$foo/bar/"`. Yes, it works. That brings the question why `$` need to be escaped in the regex (not in the shell). What does `$` not at the end of the pattern mean when `-r` option is specified?

Comment: @Cyrus I understand the difference between single and double quotes already. If you think double-quotes is the problem, then why does the first regular expression in my question works?

Comment: @LoneLearner, bash will expand $foo, then transfer the expanded result to sed command.

Comment: @Cyrus Since you guys are unnecessarily bothering about double-quotes in this question, I have rewritten the question using single-quotes only. The problem is still evident.

Comment: @gzh I have edited the question to use single-quotes only. Now you would agree that bash would not expand the variable `$foo`, right? But the problem is still there. See the updated question.

Comment: What is "this command does not work fine" vs "this works fine"? "fine" meaning what exactly?

Comment: @l'L'l Read the first sentence of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *extended regular expressions* (ERE), that is, under `-r`, `$` means the end of the line:

```
$ echo '$foo' | sed -r 's/foo$/bar/'
$bar
```

If you want it to mean something else, it has to be escaped:

```
$ echo '$foo' | sed -r 's/[$]foo$/bar/'
bar
```

#### Documentation

`man 7 regex` explains that, in *Extended Regular Expressions* (ERE), the `$` matches at the end of the line:

> '$' (matching the null string  at  the  end  of  a  line)

The same man page goes on to explain that in *Basic Regular Expressions* (BRE), which is what you get *without* `-r`, its meaning is more complicated:

> Obsolete ("basic") regular expressions differ in several respects. 
>   '|', '+', and '?' are ordinary characters and  there  is  no 
>   equivalent  for their functionality.  The delimiters for bounds are
>   "{" and "}", with '{' and '}' by themselves ordinary characters. 
>   The parentheses for nested subexpressions are "(" and ")", with '('
>   and ')' by themselves ordinary  characters.   '^'  is an ordinary
>   character except at the beginning of the RE or(!) the beginning of a
>   parenthesized subexpression, **'$' is an ordinary character except at
>   the end of the RE or(!) the end of a parenthesized subexpression,** and
>   '*' is an ordinary  character  if it appears at the beginning of the
>   RE or the beginning of a parenthesized subexpression (after a possible
>   leading '^').

Comment: Do you know why `$` would mean the end of the line even when it is not at the end of the pattern? In basic regular expression, `$` matches end of line only when it is at the end of the pattern. Why is it different for extended regular expression? How could `$` at the beginning of a pattern match an end of line anyway?

Comment: @LoneLearner I just added the manpage documentation for it.  As for why, that is not clear to me: it seems like a poor design choice.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the documentation.